# How to disable Tab Bar transition animation?

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uitabbar

I have a simple application having a tabbar below. One of the tabbar options lead to a navigation controller leading to a view leading to a second view.

```
 Tabbar Application "Option_X" -> Navigation Controller -> First View -> Second View
```

Now, when i reach the Second View and tap the button "Option_X" again on the tabbar i get back to First View. This is fine, but, during this operation, views get switched with a sliding animation. 
I want to disable the animation so that the transition will be a static switch (I am on Second View, i press and suddenly i am back on first view).
How do i?

Comment: in which method you turn on the tabbar? try to turn on the tabbar inside this method. - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated;

Comment: the tabbar is added via storyboard. What do you precisely mean i'm supposed to do?